# How to custom a slider bar with different color border based on slider ticks?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, slider, styles

I have to create a slider that has certain given tick values (e.g 100,304,605,..). I want to style a slider in such a way that for example from 0-100 the bar to have a color, and from 100-304 a different color and so on.

Here is an e.g. of what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Here is my .xaml code:

```
<Slider Style="{StaticResource MyCustomStyleForSlider}" //the style to be applied
Name="MyTimeSlider" 
Width="130" 
Minimum="0" 
Maximum="{Binding MaxTimeFrames}" 
Value="{Binding TimeFrame}" 
TickPlacement="BottomRight" 
TickFrequency="1" 
IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" 
Margin="1,4,1,1" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: Custom control is a better candidate for this. You will need new dependency property to assign ranges (value and color) and some logic to draw that. This may not fit into xaml (read - you will need code behind).

Answer (score 1):

Would subclass `Slider` and add a dependency property that supplies a list of colors or brushes to be used. In the class i would recalculate a `LinearGradient` for the `Background` whenever the `Ticks` property (which supplies a list of ticks that separate the areas) changes. To make hard cuts add a different color at the same offset as the previous gradient stop, should be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to override the regular slider template, it is pretty lengthy, but here is an example:http://pastebin.com/XVuRLuWp (code to long to paste here).

In order to change the background focus on `x:Key="HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBackground"`. I have already made it show a couple of different colors.